# compare user's input in a python list

Tags: python-3.x

The question is related to Python

I have this list:

```
a=[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]

# I ask the user to enter a  number

user_number = input("Enter a number")
```

What I need is to display the numbers of the list that are smaller than than user_input

Any hint please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can `for` loop through the list.

```
for numbers in a:
    if number < int(user_input)
        print(number)
```

Comment: Thank you! The code needed a colon
if number < int(user_input):